# Is there a way to pair my PC with 2 bluetooth headphones?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, bluetooth-3.0

Is there a way to pair my PC with 2 bluetooth headphones?

Can anyone list the type of usb bluetooth dongle I would need and type of headphones to do this? Ideally I just want to have one bluetooth usb dongle connected to my PC, that sends the same audio to 2 different sets of bluetooth headphones at good quality.